# XmlNodeList y XmlElement diferencias

Tags: c#, xml

estoy estudiando algo de C# y he visto un tutorial donde en un archivo XML se busca el valor de dos variables y se muestra en consola. Pero no comprendo estas lineas, he buscado informacion por internet y logro encontrar el mismo ejemplo pero no encuentro una explicacion que me haga entender completamente

```
   public string GuardarXML(string XML)
        {
            XmlDocument data_xml = new XmlDocument();
            data_xml.LoadXml(XML);
  XmlNodeList node_equipos = data_xml.GetElementsByTagName("equipos");

            XmlNodeList equipos = ((XmlElement)node_equipos[0]).GetElementsByTagName("equipo");

            foreach (XmlElement equipo in equipos) {
                string nombre = equipo.GetElementsByTagName("nombre")[0].InnerText;
                string pais = equipo.GetElementsByTagName("pais")[0].InnerText;
            }
            return "Proceso realizado con exito";
        }
```

Logro entender un poco pero por ejemplo no comprendo la linea

```
XmlNodeList equipos = ((XmlElement)node_equipos[0]).GetElementsByTagName("equipo");
```

Por que node_equipos se convierte a XmlElement? a lo que he entendido tendria mas sentido que fuera convertido a XmlNode y no XmlElement, cual es la difernecia entre estos dos y por que se debe convertir a Elemento? realmente no logro ver la diferencia entre estos dos

Comment: Por favor anadir el ejemplo del XML a la pregunta, para que podemos probar este codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente lo conviertes XmlElement para poder acceder al método GetElementsByTagName ya que XmlNode  no posee ese método.

> Cual es la diferencia entre estos dos y por que se debe convertir a Elemento?

XmlElement es una subclase de XmlNode por lo que cada XmlElement viene siendo un XmlNode.